# turning arrays of data into a table in php

Tags: php, mysql

Please can anyone suggest how to approach this problem I have.

Using this query:

`$query1 = "SELECT * FROM assessments WHERE pupil_id=288";`

I have a number rows coming from the db for A pupil who has had 3 assessments at different times (as flagged by the assessment_id column)

```
Array ( [assessment_id] => 47 [pupil_id] => 288 [assessblock_id] => 13 [Speaking] => P2ic [Listening] => P2ib...


Array ( [assessment_id] => 49 [pupil_id] => 288 [assessblock_id] => 14 [Speaking] => P9a [Listening] => P9a...

Array ( [assessment_id] => 171 [pupil_id] => 288 [assessblock_id] => 15 [Speaking] => H1b [Listening] => H1b...
```

I need to turn these into a table like this. It shows the three grades awarded for each subject.

```
------------------------------
subject  | assessment id | next assessment id| last assessment id |
Speaking | P2ic          |  P9a              | H1b                |
```

My question is how best to go about moving from my rows of data to this table? Its easy if there is only 1 row of course. I can't see how to add in the third column (second set of results) because at this point I have already used a `</tr>`

Here is some of the code I have tried:

```
$query1 = "SELECT * FROM assessments WHERE pupil_id=288 AND assessblock_id='15'";
$result = $conn->query($query1);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

        ?>
        <table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <tr><th>Subject</th><th>grade</th></tr>
    <?php 
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            foreach ($subjectListArray as $subject){
                 $sub = str_replace(" ", "_", $subject);
                 echo '<tr><td>'.$subject.'</td><td>'.$row[$sub].'</tr>';
            }
        }// endwhile
        echo '</table>';
    }//endif
```

This produces a column of the subjects and a second for the first assessment block.

In the query above I have assessblock_id=15 - so I only get 1 row. I remove this to get all three rows - but then my table breaks down.

HOw can I get the second and third assessments into my table...

I can't see how to add in the second and third assessments blocks directly from the qy

Comment: What have you tried? Show the code you've written to written so far. ATM, it looks as if you're asking us to write the code for you, which is of course not what this site is for

Comment: Why is `P2ic` an `assessment id`? I don't get DB relation to output..

Comment: Add your database dump and the php code you are working so far. It will helps us understand your problem better.

Comment: no - I am not expecting you guys to write me the code. I have tied a lot of things... was hard to get my head around the question. The figures 'P2ic' etc are assessments grades given at that assessment_id time

Comment: Forgot closing tag for 2nd td `echo '<tr><td>'.$subject.'</td><td>'.$row[$sub].'</td></tr>';`

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
     border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
     die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM assessments WHERE pupil_id=288";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
     echo "<table><tr><th>subject</th><th>assessment id</th><th>next assessment id</th><th>last assessment id</th></tr>";
     // output data of each row
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
         echo "<tr><td>" . $row['subject']. "</td><td>" . $row["assessment_id']"</td><td>" . $row['next_assessment_id']. "</td><td>" . $row['last_assessment_id']. "</td></tr>";
     }
     echo "</table>";
} else {
     echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close();
?> 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is this? An answer should have a write up of what you are doing and why.

Comment: The question is `My question is how best to go about moving from my rows of data to this table? Its easy if there is only 1 row of course.`. The OP already can output; is looking for restructuring it..

Comment: thanks but this wont show the data in the way i want it. Perhaps I didn't make my question clear enough

Comment: next time make proper form of it

Answer (score 0):

in the end I decided to approach this a different way. I spent sometime trying to make my question clear, though I obviously failed. I had wanted to stick to just 1 query. In the end I had 3 queries to get the three columns. That seemed to work.